# How to set a global numerical limit for several sequences in Python?

Tags: python, sequence

I am attempting to compute a solution to a problem related to imposing a limit on two numerical sequences.

Here is what I have so far.

```
print "\x1b[31mWe need to declare a limit for x in the equation 90*(x*x) + 2*x."
new_index = raw_input("type limit here>")
test_1 = int(new_index)

print "\x1b[31mWe need to declare a limit for n in the equation y+((91+(90*(x-1)))*n).\x1b[0m I suggest 3 (or up to 10). Any two points when plotted on a graph will describe a line of constant slope. To see only the first sequence of numbers put 0."
print "Enter your limit value here.\x1b[0m"
now_test = raw_input("type limit here>")
new_test = int(now_test)

def dr1_ld1_91_91(x):
    y = 90*(x*x) + 2*x
    print "(nonn)", "(nonn)", y
    for n in xrange(1, new_test):
        new_y = y+((91+(90*(x-1)))*n)
        print new_y, new_y
    while new_y < new_test:
        return

for x in xrange(1, test_1): 
    dr1_ld1_91_91(x)#=182
```

I am having a difficult time understanding how to set the range. So I am having a user declare that `test_1` and `new_test` are the variables that are used to limit the sequences. But I need a 'global limit' that is not related to iterations of the value of `x` and `n` but rather are limits on the absolute value of the sequences.

So I am attempting to set the limit so that `test_1` and `new_test` grow as large as they need to for `y` and `new_y` to stay at the threshold of a global limit.

So my current output looks like this:

```
(nonn) (nonn) 92
183 183
274 274
365 365
456 456
(nonn) (nonn) 364
545 545
726 726
907 907
1088 1088
(nonn) (nonn) 816
1087 1087
1358 1358
1629 1629
1900 1900
(nonn) (nonn) 1448
1809 1809
2170 2170
2531 2531
2892 2892
```

The `nonn` denotes the first equation and the sequence beneath it denotes the second equation.

I need both of these sequences to print sufficient terms to populate out to a *global limit* (for example, 10,000). I am not advanced enough as a programmer to convert the limit from the user submitted value to a global limit.

I cannot see the `enter code here`.

Comment: It is really unclear what you are trying to accomplish. _Why_ are you doing all these limited-ranges-in-ranges? What are you _actually_ trying to solve by doing this?

Comment: All of the terms produced by this function are composite. So I am trying to sum up all the terms beneath a global limit thereby producing a very narrow type of sieve. You can recover the composite number in base-10 form by multiplying the printed number by 90 and adding 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making sure I understand the problem:

```
x is an integer in [1 .. max_x]

y = 90 * x**2 + 2 * x

z = y + ((91 + (90 * (x - 1))) * n)
  = 90*x*n + n + y
  = (90*x + 1)*n + (90*x**2 + 2*x)
  = 90 * x**2 + (90 * n + 2) * x + n

n is an integer > 0
```

and for each `x` you want to find `max_n` such that `z(x, max_n) <= limit_value < z(x, max_n+1)`?

If `n > 0` and `x > 0`, `z(n,x)` is positive parabola (opens upward) and finding an integer `max_n` for a given `x` and `max_z` should be straightforward:

```
let k be a real number in [0..1) and max_n' == max_n + k

max_z = (90*x + 1)*max_n' + (90*x**2 + 2*x)

max_n' = (max_z - (90*x**2 + 2*x)) / (90*x + 1)

max_n = floor(max_n') = floor((max_z - (90*x**2 + 2*x)) / (90*x + 1))
```

(The following code assumes Python 2.7):

```
import math

FMT = "{:>8} {:>8} {:>8}".format

def get_int(prompt, lo=None, hi=None):
    while True:
        try:
            value = int(raw_input(prompt))
            if (lo is None or lo <= value) and (hi is None or value <= hi):
                return value
        except ValueError:   # could not parse input as int
            pass             # try again

def max_x(max_y):
    # y = 90*x**2 + 2*x
    # 0 = 90*x**2 + 2*x - y
    # Using the quadratic formula,
    # x = (-2 +/- sqrt(4 + 360*y)) / 180
    # We are only interested in the +ve solution:
    discr_rt = math.sqrt(4 + 360 * max_y)
    x = (discr_rt - 2.) / 180.
    # and we want to round down to an int
    return int(math.floor(x))

def max_n(x, max_z):
    a = 90*x + 1
    y = (90*x + 2)*x
    nf = float(max_z - y) / a
    return int(math.floor(nf))

def z(x, n):
    a = 90*x + 1
    y = (90*x + 2)*x
    return a*n + y

def main():
    max_z = get_int("Please enter int value for max_z: ", 1, 10000)
    max_y = max_z
    max_x_val = max_x(max_y)

    for x in xrange(1, max_x_val + 1):
        max_n_val = max_n(x, max_z)
        if max_n_val < 1:
            break
        y = (90*x + 2)*x
        print(FMT("(nonn)", "(nonn)", y))
        for n in xrange(1, max_n_val + 1):
            z_val = z(x, n)
            print(FMT(z_val, z_val, ""))

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

which produces output like the following:

```
Please enter int value for max_z: 2000
  (nonn)   (nonn)       92
     183      183         
     274      274         
     365      365         
     456      456         
     547      547         
     638      638         
     729      729         
     820      820         
     911      911         
    1002     1002         
    1093     1093         
    1184     1184         
    1275     1275         
    1366     1366         
    1457     1457         
    1548     1548         
    1639     1639         
    1730     1730         
    1821     1821         
    1912     1912         
  (nonn)   (nonn)      364
     545      545         
     726      726         
     907      907         
    1088     1088         
    1269     1269         
    1450     1450         
    1631     1631         
    1812     1812         
    1993     1993         
  (nonn)   (nonn)      816
    1087     1087         
    1358     1358         
    1629     1629         
    1900     1900         
  (nonn)   (nonn)     1448
    1809     1809
```

**Edit** updated per comment!

Comment: That is extremely close. The max_x value produces the sequence 92, 364, 816..... I need the limit of that sequence to be the same absolute value as the limit you set for max_z. So the behavior of max_z is *exactly correct* but the behavior of max_x is not. How can max_x be evaluated such that y prints to the same limit as max_z? BTW, thank you for responding!

Comment: You really nailed it!

Comment: I don't know if this is the appropriate way to do this but I would be interested in hiring you to do a little bit of coding for me. What you coded represents a slice of a bigger project but I suspect that you would be able to complete it in very little time given how rapidly you assessed the original issue.... At any rate I do not know how to contact you other than making a comment.... IS this a "legal" way of communicating in this forum?

Comment: @JWJeffHelkenberg: I am interested; you can contact me at hugh_bothwell (at) hotmail.com